# Why the accuracy and validation_accuracy are drastically different on the same dataset (no normalization or dropout)?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm new to tensorflow 2.0 and I'm running a very simple model that classifies a 1d time series of fixed size (100 values) into one of two classes:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(100, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
```

I have a dataset of ~660,000 labeled examples that I feed into the model with batch_size=256. When I train the NN for 10 epochs, using the same data as a validation dataset

```
history = model.fit(training_dataset,
                epochs=10,
                verbose=1,
                validation_data=training_dataset)
```

I got the following output

```
Epoch 1/10
2573/2573 [==============================] - 55s 21ms/step - loss: 0.5271 - acc: 0.7433 - val_loss: 3.4160 - val_acc: 0.4282
Epoch 2/10
2573/2573 [==============================] - 55s 21ms/step - loss: 0.5673 - acc: 0.7318 - val_loss: 3.3634 - val_acc: 0.4282
Epoch 3/10
2573/2573 [==============================] - 55s 21ms/step - loss: 0.5628 - acc: 0.7348 - val_loss: 2.6422 - val_acc: 0.4282
Epoch 4/10
2573/2573 [==============================] - 57s 22ms/step - loss: 0.5589 - acc: 0.7314 - val_loss: 2.6799 - val_acc: 0.4282
Epoch 5/10
2573/2573 [==============================] - 56s 22ms/step - loss: 0.5683 - acc: 0.7278 - val_loss: 2.3266 - val_acc: 0.4282
Epoch 6/10
2573/2573 [==============================] - 55s 21ms/step - loss: 0.5644 - acc: 0.7276 - val_loss: 2.3177 - val_acc: 0.4282
Epoch 7/10
2573/2573 [==============================] - 56s 22ms/step - loss: 0.5664 - acc: 0.7255 - val_loss: 2.3848 - val_acc: 0.4282
Epoch 8/10
2573/2573 [==============================] - 55s 21ms/step - loss: 0.5711 - acc: 0.7237 - val_loss: 2.2369 - val_acc: 0.4282
Epoch 9/10
2573/2573 [==============================] - 55s 22ms/step - loss: 0.5739 - acc: 0.7189 - val_loss: 2.6969 - val_acc: 0.4282
Epoch 10/10
2573/2573 [==============================] - 219s 85ms/step - loss: 0.5778 - acc: 0.7213 - val_loss: 2.5662 - val_acc: 0.4282
```

How come the accuracy during the training is so different from the validation step, when run on the same dataset? I tried to find some explanation but it seems that such problems usually arise when people use BatchNormalization or Dropout layers, which is not the case here.

Comment: A smaller accuracy in your case shows that the model is not able to classify the time series as expected. Consider using an RNN model for time series classification. Refer to [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#recurrent_neural_network) doc. Also, we can use a 1D convolution too.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The only reason I'm using dense layers is to provide a minimal example.

Comment: Try to shuffle your data before training NN on it. If this will bring acc and val_acc closer together I will explain why, so not to hypothesize match for now.

Comment: I increased shuffle buffer from 100,000 to 660,000 (so it's true shuffling) and now the accuracy matches the validation accuracy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information above, I may assume your data has strong dependencies on examples that are closer to each other in time series.
Therefore, NN data flow will likely be like this:

- NN takes the first batch, calculates the loss, and updates the weights and biases
- the cycle repeats on and on
- but since examples in batches not that far away from each other in time series it is easier for NN to update weights accordingly, making loss reasonably low for every next batch

When it is time for validation NN just calculates the loss without updating the weights,
so you end up with NN that learned how to infer on a small portion of the data but do not generalize well on the whole dataset.

That is why validation error is different from training even on the same dataset.

And a list of reasons is not limited to this, this is just one assumption.